# How to get sum of the score from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have table in my data base which is storing the score of users table looks like this.

```
 id     user_id  user_score
    2748    371     3
    2253    353     2
    2254    353     2
    2255    353     2
    2256    353     2
    2257    353     2
    2258    353     2
    2259    353     2
```

I want to calculate each users total score from this table and need to out put user name like this

```
 user_id user_Score
    357     x
    367     y
    354     z
```

Here x>y>z
Php code i am writing is something looks like this

```
 <?php
//Expected query is contains user_id and user_query
      $query="Expected query";
      $connection=mysqli_connect("Connection varables");
      $data=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
      echo "User name:";
      echo $row['user_id'];
      echo "</br>";
      echo "Score:";
      echo $row['user_score'];
      echo "</br>";
     }
    ?>
```

How to do this?.

Comment: What is the expected output based on the data you provided?

Comment: @MarkLeiber i have reposted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(user_score) as max_score
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY max_score DESC
```

should be what you are looking for if I understood you correctly.

It gives you for each user the user's `user_id` as well as the user's highest score, sorted by the highscores.

**Edit:** If you are looking for the sum of all scores per user, this query will do the trick instead:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(user_score) as score_sum
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY score_sum DESC
```

Comment: I don't think `SUM()` is what you are looking for, it will give you the sum of all scores by one user. What exactly are you trying to improve? Your PHP code?

Comment: SELECT user_id,SUM(user_score) as max_score
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY max_score DESC its worked perfevtly fine for me.

Comment: Well, as I said, this won't give you the maximum score for each user, but rather the sum of all scores per user

Comment: That is what i am looking for my English is so bad.

Comment: how to echo out the total score

Comment: i got just echo '$row['sum_score']';

Comment: Please update your original question with what you got!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't see any code in your post?

Comment: What code you are expecting here it is mysqli question

Comment: Well, you are trying to output your results using PHP, aren't you? Please post the PHP code you are using right now.

Comment: added php code as well i hopes this is what you are expected

Comment: What exactly is the output of the script you posted and what output are you expecting? I don't see how your script could echo `$row['sum_score']`

Comment: what ever your answer is the solution can you check once again?.